# call a wcf that is uploaded to a host 404 not found why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf

I develop a `wcf` application ,so it works fine in local pc ,but when i publish it and i upload the published file i couldn't reference that service to my third application .

let me explain that ,the published file is like this :

[image]

The config file is like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfServiceLibrary1.IService1">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
        <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. --> 
        <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

as you know in `webconfig` there is `http://localhost:8733` and i change it to `asp.spadsystem.com` but no result.

So i added this reference to my application `asp.spadsystem.com/WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1.svc` ,but the visual third application can't find the service .

I am so new in wcf.

Comment: Did you remove or update the identity element under endpoint?

Comment: @JamieSee No i didn't edit anything

Comment: It appears you have built a WCF Service *Library*.   Did you do as the comment in the app.config file said - **When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries.**

Comment: You should try removing that element. Also, if the HTTP Activation feature is not enabled on your server WCF services won't work. What happens if you go to the URL for the service in a web browser?

Comment: @JamieSee which url should i check ?

Comment: The full url for the location of the .svc within your app, i.e. `http://myserver.com/mywebservicefolder/mywebservice.svc`.

Comment: @JamieSee when i call http://asp.spadsystem.com/WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1.svc ,result:404 not found

Comment: @tim yes exactly this is a wcf library ,but i upload the published file

Comment: Do you know if you are using nginx for your web server and not IIS, or is the nginx being used as a proxy? Maybe try looking at this article and see if it helps: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/nginx/wcf-service.

Comment: If you are using IIS try running DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:WCF-HTTP-Activation45 on your server.

Comment: @JamieSee you know i don't have any permission to do this on my server

Comment: @JamieSee i think the problem is my webconfig ,

Comment: I highly suspect that you are missing a feature on the web server, either WCF-HTTP-Activation45 (for .NET 4) or WCF-HTTP-Activation (for .NET 3.5). Can you get your server admin to add the appropriate feature using the DISM command or the Server Manager GUI?